# Mapping HBase Tables(NameSpace) with Apache Phoenix(Schema)

Tags: namespaces, hbase, schema, apache-phoenix

I have created a HBase table named `test` under the namespace `np`(np:test) and loaded records as below .

`create 'np:test','cf'
put 'np:test','1','cf:c1','99'`

Also I have created a schema 'np' in phoenix and created a phoenix table to map hbase as below.
`create schema 'np';
CREATE TABLE "test"(PK VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, "np"."c1" VARCHAR);`

Can able to scan the inserted data through HBase table but not through the same in Phoenix Table. Mapping was not done..
In addition to this, I also tried creating view as below
`CREATE VIEW "test"(PK VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, "np"."c1" VARCHAR);`
Getting

`Error: ERROR 505 (42000): Table is read only. (state=42000,code=505)
org.apache.phoenix.schema.ReadOnlyTableException: ERROR 505 (42000): Table is read only.
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.ensureTableCreated(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1069)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.createTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1434)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTableInternal(MetaDataClient.java:2624)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTable(MetaDataClient.java:1040)
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.CreateTableCompiler$2.execute(CreateTableCompiler.java:212)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:393)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:376)
        at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:374)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:363)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.execute(PhoenixStatement.java:1707)
        at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:822)
        at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:732)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:813)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:686)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:291)`

Please help to resolve HBase-Phoenix Table Mapping.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: did you set the properties for namespace? phoenix.schema.isNamespaceMappingEnabled https://phoenix.apache.org/namspace_mapping.html

Comment: Yea.. have added this property already.. but still it doesn't recognize the schema.

Comment: try changing create table to `create table 'np'.'test' ` In HBase I would create the namespace, and let Phoenix associate the table to the Namespace in the create command